# Mule Facebook Connector error: "Could not extract OAuth verifier."

Tags: facebook, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I tried to build very simple application via Mule to connect to Facebook.
I followed this demo: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZDYC95DSRs)

The final components will be like this: 
[image]

The Problem once I run application and hit the URL: http://localhost:1111/auth
I got the following message in the browser:

```
Could not extract OAuth verifier.
```

Also I get the following error in the console:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.security.oauth.exception.AuthorizationCodeNotFoundException
    at org.mule.security.oauth.processor.ExtractAuthorizationCodeMessageProcessor.extractAuthorizationCode(ExtractAuthorizationCodeMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.processor.ExtractAuthorizationCodeMessageProcessor.process(ExtractAuthorizationCodeMessageProcessor.java:39)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
```

The complete configuration XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:facebook="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook/current/mule-facebook.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1111" host="localhost" port="1111" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <facebook:config-with-oauth name="Facebook" consumerKey="111974699389920" consumerSecret="7406759445e528542668752d135c422a" doc:name="Facebook">
        <facebook:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="1111" remotePort="1111" path="/*"/>
    </facebook:config-with-oauth>
    <flow name="facebookFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1111" path="/auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook" doc:name="Facebook"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.OAuthAccessTokenId != null]">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Authorization is done succefully"/>
                <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="Facebook Authorization Successful"/>
                <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Authorization Failed"/>
                <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="Facebook Authorization Failed"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

What is the cause of this problem?? how to avoid it??

Answer (score 0):

You have to hit http listener url not the callback url.

listener URL :  http://localhost:1111  -- use this after running application.
callback url :  http://localhost:1111/auth

Please let me know if it helps !

Aman.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I should hit  http://localhost:1111 I tried but nothing change, still get "Could not extract OAuth verifier."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when setting up OAuth2 for a Mule flow calling Google Spreadsheets.

Sometimes when you copy and paste the client id and secret from the API, it brings additional leading or trailing spaces which can cause the authorization to fail.

You should be hitting the URL for HTTP listener element you have as the message source for your flow. The API you are accessing should redirect to the Callback URL after you authorize successfully. These adjustments worked for me, hope they help!